# Dealing with MFC form 'text' as char type or regular string type

Tags: c++, c, string, mfc, char

While modifying MFC form written by others, with Visual Studio 2012, I encountered a problem.

In the form, there is a input box which takes the entire path of the file.
ex) `C:\folder1\test_file.wav`
And in the code, `this->tb_path->Text` contains this.

First problem is that I cannot find a method to deal with `this->tb_path->Text` as 
`char*` or `char` type array to use methods in `string.h`

In status quo, code uses

`system:: String ^fileName = this->tb_path->Text + "_re";`

to modify the text, but this actually hampers various modifications of file path.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think any of your language tags are correct.  Your code is not `C`, and it is not `C++`.

Comment: Are you using actually WinForms with C++/CLI? What does MFC have to do with this question? Strings are going to be UTF-16, so you will need to use a wide-character type.

Comment: What type are: this, tb_type and Text?

Comment: If this were C++/CLI, then the type `String` would be in namespace `System`, not `system`. Only the OP can tell, which code they are using, which platform they are targeting, and which programming language they are using. As written, the question doesn't appear to make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
System::String ^fileName = gcnew System::String(this->tb_path->Text + "_re");
```

or may be

```
System::String ^fileName = gcnew System::String(this->tb_path->Text + _T("_re"));
```

It seems to me you are not doing a required allocation in memory with gcnew, an then you get garbage inside your string from uninitialized memory.

Comment: Wouldn't the + operator do the allocation for you? You are just making a new copy of the string object resulting from concatenation.